# Python getters and setters: which one is called in this case and why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

- There is a class `HasBody` for representing some object with `body` attribute such that `body['a']['b']['parameters']` is a list of dicts with keys: `name`, `val` (strucutre example in code below).
- Class `HasBody` makes use of class `Parameter` which is basically a data class storing `name` and `val`.
- `HasBody.parameters` (getter) returns a list of `Parameter` instances.
- setter converts passed list of `Parameter` instances to dict and writes it to `body` variable.

Below I provide full working code and outputs. My questions:

**1. How to modify the code so that changing single parameter changes `h.body`?**

**2. Why getter is called instead of setter?**

**3. What are some other potentially unobvious cases when I could make similar mistake?**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parameter():
    name: str
    val: str
        
    def __hash__(self): 
        return hash(self.name)
    
    def as_dict(self):
        return {"name": self.name, "val": self.val}

class HasBody:
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body 
        
    @property
    def parameters(self) -> List[Parameter]:
        print("Parameters getter called!")
        return [Parameter(**param_dict) for param_dict in self.body['a']['b']['parameters']]
    
    @parameters.setter
    def parameters(self, new_parameters: List[Parameter]):
        print(f"Parameters setter called with: {new_parameters}")
        self.body['a']['b']['parameters'] = [param.as_dict() for param in new_parameters]
   
    def edit_param_value(self, param_name: str, new_value: str) -> Parameter:
        """Find param with given `param_name`and edit it's `val`. Return edited parameter."""
        for param in self.parameters:
            if param.name == param_name:
                param.val = new_value
                return param
        
        raise ValueError(f'Parameter with name {param_name} not found')

some_body = {"a": {"b": {"parameters": [{"name": "p_name", "val": "p_val"}]}}}
h = HasBody(some_body)
```

I printed out what happens when I either access `h.parameters` directly or via `edit_parameter` method:

```py
print("LOADED body['a']['b']['parameters']")
print(h.body['a']['b']['parameters'])

print("CALL TO edit_param_value")
print(h.edit_param_value('param_name', 'new_val')) # Doesnt affect h.body!

print("body['a']['b']['parameters'] AFTER CALL")
print(h.body['a']['b']['parameters'])

print("WRITING TO h.parameters")
h.parameters = [Parameter(name = 'p1', val = 'd'), Parameter(name = 'p2', val = 'xd')]

print("FINAL body['a']['b']['parameters']")
print(h.body['a']['b']['parameters']) # Affects h.body
```

```
LOADED body['a']['b']['parameters']
[{'name': 'p_name', 'val': 'p_val'}]
CALL TO edit_param_value
Parameters getter called!
Parameter(name='p_name', val='new_val')
BODY AFTER CALL
[{'name': 'p_name', 'val': 'p_val'}]
WRITING TO h.parameters
Parameters setter called with: [Parameter(name='p1', val='d'), Parameter(name='p2', val='xd')]
FINAL BODY
[{'name': 'p1', 'val': 'd'}, {'name': 'p2', 'val': 'xd'}]
```

Comment: Your setter only gets called when you assign to `self.parameters`. (`self.parameters = some_value`) Your getter gets called when you access `self.parameters`. (`for param in self.parameters`). Your assignment never actually does anything (`param.val = new_value`) except assign to a `list` of generated instances `Parameter` that are never assigned to anything associated with your class `HasBody`.

Comment: Also, are you aware that the `dataclasses` module has an [`asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) function?

Comment: @Axe319 1.thanks for `asdict`, I didn't know. 2.I see now why `edit_param_value` doesn't affect body, but I don't know how to write it so that it does what I want. Do you have any idea?'

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be controlling access to the wrong attribute. If `h.body` is the access you care about, just make that a `property`.

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass


@dataclass
class Parameter():
    name: str
    val: str


class HasBody:
    def __init__(self, body):
        self._body = body 
        self.parameters = [
            Parameter(**param_dict) for param_dict in self._body['a']['b']['parameters']
        ]
        
    @property
    def body(self):
        result = self._body
        result['a']['b']['parameters'] = [asdict(p) for p in self.parameters]
        return result
   
    def edit_param_value(self, param_name: str, new_value: str) -> Parameter:
        """Find param with given `param_name`and edit it's `val`. Return edited parameter."""
        for param in self.parameters:
            if param.name == param_name:
                param.val = new_value
                return param
        
        raise ValueError(f'Parameter with name {param_name} not found')

some_body = {"a": {"b": {"parameters": [{"name": "p_name", "val": "p_val"}]}}}
h = HasBody(some_body)
print(h.body)
print(h.edit_param_value('p_name', 'new_val'))
print(h.body)
h.parameters = [Parameter(name='p1', val='d'), Parameter(name='p2', val='xd')]
print(h.body)
print(h.body['a']['b']['parameters'])
```

Since it looks you want `self.parameters` to simply be a `list` of `dataclasses`, initialize it in your `__init__` and then mutate the objects as you deem necessary.

Whenever you want `self.body` to display the body in `dict` form, simply generate the parameters at that point with `asdict` and return the modified `self.body`.

Edit:

It seems you want to access control to the `self.body` `dict` itself. This is not possible unless it is an instance of a class you have control over.

This would create much confusion even if you could do it. This is because `some_body` and `self.body` are the same mutable object. If `self.body` is modified, so is `some_body` and vice versa. Imagine trying to determine the context in which `some_body`/`self.body` is modified, as an instance of your class or outside of it.

It would be possible to subclass `dict` and `list` and modify `__setitem__` on them.

```
class BodyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, hasbody_inst):
        self.hasbody_inst = hasbody_inst

    def __setitem__(self, key, val) -> None:
        if key == 'parameters':
            self.hasbody_inst.parameters = val
        return super().__setitem__(key, val)
```

I do not recommend it. There are many situations you couldn't control or would miss. Additionally, the amount of work it would take to get it to work for every situation would be extensive and any user of your code would do a double-take.

Comment: Sorry, I see that didn't specify that I need to be able to do all the following:
- mutate `body` (like `h.body["a]["not_b"] = some_new_val`)
- overwrite value of a single parameter (should affect both `body` and `parameters`)
- overwrite whole `parameters` with providing new list of parameters (same as above)
I think that your code doesn't allow for example direct modification of `body`. Any further ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. `h.body["a"]["not_b"] = some_new_val` is not modifying the parameters since the parameters are under `h.body['a']['b']`. In order to control `h.body["a"]["b"]['parameters'] = new_parameters` you would need to control the type of `h.body["a"]["b"]['parameters']` which currently is a `list` of `dict`. While it's possible to subclass `dict` and `list` and modify `__setitem__` on them, doing so would have a cost much larger than the benefit.

Comment: I mean that in another place in my code (it's actually just a part of bigger program) I need to modify other parts of `body` than parameters. Thus I also need to be able to mutate `body` itself, not via changing `parameters`.